# How to get the loaded image path in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have loaded an image file via pygame.

now i want to get this image name..

```
image = pyagme.image.load(image)
```

now i'm looking for something like this:

```
print image.path()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Surface` in pygame has no knowledge about how it was created (manually/loaded from file or string/etc.).

Since you already know the path of the image when you load it, just keep it (don't overwrite the variable).

```
image_path = "/some/path/to/image.png"
image = pyagme.image.load(image_path)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'v done eventually.. I have a pretty long code and if there were such a function it could save some unwanted mess..

Comment: Maybe you should use the Sprite class, which basically holds together a Surface (img) and its position in form of a Rect (rect).

Comment: @sloth How we can get file path, when number of images loaded from folder using loop and passing it to sprite then selecting images using index based on action. Here i want to display filename in screen.